# Documents folder's name

Tags: windows-10, documents

I have changed the path where the "Documents" folder is stored, moving it from the C: unit to the D: unit (another local unit of my PC). Initially I made a mistake moving under D: and not under D:\User\Documents where I actually want it and also the name of the folder was changed, from "Documents" to "D:". Now I have removed the folder in the new correct position, but I also would like to rename it; unfortunately it seems impossible and moreover the name showed in the property window is "Documents". I attach two pictures (italian language) in order to explain the situation.

[image: The name of the folder "Documents" is "D:"]

[image: The name in property window is correctly "Documents"]

My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Does the **Properties** -> **Location** tab not allow you to move it again? If not, you could try the **Restore Default** button and start again. The name is set in the **General tab**, but you can change it only from the full path, not the quick access short-cut. I hope you back up everything in the directory before you change any settings.

Answer (score 2):

The safest way to move any of the special system folders is through the Location (*Percorso*) tab of the properties. Nirsoft's [Special Folders View](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/special_folders_view.html) makes it easy to list them. Right-click on *My Documents*, which may or may not be *Document*, select *Folder Properties*, and then the *Location* tab.

Note that, in the example below, the generic *My Documents* special folder is the folder *Documents*, a level of indirection, and that in Windows Explorer it shows as just *Documents*.

[image: Special Folders]